# Identifier 'normal_push' is not in camel case

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I'm trying to build a project with webpack, but I get an error:

```
Identifier 'normal_push' is not in camel case
```

Javascript and webpack config file here: https://jsfiddle.net/6ea01yst/1/

How fix it problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is causing an error, but try changing it to `normalPush`. Can you link your webpack config?

Comment: Webpack config here: https://jsfiddle.net/6ea01yst/1/

Comment: It's a linter that's erroring. It's trying to tell you that javascript prefers camel case function names and variable names over snake case (like you have here). You should change your variable and function names to camel case (eg: thisIsCamelCase), so that you're consistent with the entire rest of the JS community. In this case, change your function name to `normalPush`, and your linter will be happy. Do the same with your `safari_push`, `lib_analytics`, and `current_state`, since that'll be what it complains about next.